# trying to get string to char array, help me get just the required characters in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i'm trying to convert a string to char array; it goes fine for 3 letters, but some weird chars come for longer strings.
the script works fine till i print the whole array at once...

```
std::string word;
    std::cout<< "enter word: ";
    cin>>word;
    cin.ignore();
    //std::cout<< word ":"<<word.length();
    int len=word.length();
    char char1[len-1];
    cout<<"\n";
    for (int a=0;a<len;a++)
    {
        char1[a]=word.at(a);
        std::cout<<char1[a];
    }

cout<<"\ncheckline: "<<char1;
```

for input "abcd"
output is "abcdπ"

Comment: `char char1[len-1];` is a variable length array and is not standard C++.  Why are you trying to convert the `std::string` into a c string?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Take a look at [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Answer (score 2):

You have four problems.

Firstly, the size of an array must be compile time constant. `len` is not a compile time constant, so the program is ill-formed according to the standard. Henceforth, I shall assume that your compiler supports "Variable Length Array" language extension. In standard C++, you must allocate dynamic memory if the size is determined at run time.

Secondly, you allocate too little memory, and overflow your buffer. If you allocate memory for `len - 1` characters, then the last valid index is `len - 1 - 1`. Writing to `char1[len - 1]` as you do, has undefined behaviour. `char1[len]` would be required for `len` characters.

Thirdly, you didn't terminate the string with null. The standard requires that any string inserted into a stream must be null terminated. However, you pass `char1` into `std::cout` even though it does not contain a null terminated string. The behaviour is undefined. Note, that would have to also remember to allocate memory for this null termination character: `char1[len + 1];` ... `char1[len] = '\0'`.

Lastly, what you're attempting is probably pointless. Re-view the reasons why you think you need to do this. I suspect that those reasons are misguided.

Comment: tried different ways...i didnt know about the null termination, im new to c++ haha thanks. im just trying to make a sort of jumble words solution